# How to correctly fetch data to array with bind_params in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, fetch

I am currently trying to execute some MySQL query and save the results into an array using bind_params for 2 params: `userUniqueId (String)` and `limit (used to LIMIT query records)`. I've tried to do sth on my own but seems the code does not work properly. I've tried different ways to do that but still nothing. Can you try to help me? Query works fine cause I've tested it in phpMyAdmin The function I want to write must fetch records into and array and then I would like to `json_encode` that array using that array as a result of the function.

Here is my function code:

```
public function getUserFavouriteRecipes($user_unique_id, $limit) {
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT recipe.`unique_id`, recipe.`title`, recipe.`img_tumbnail_link`, recipe.`add_date`, recipe.`kitchen_type`, recipe.`meal_type`, user.`name`, user.`surname`, 
                                    (SELECT count(*) from `like` WHERE recipe.`unique_id` = `like`.`recipe_unique_id_fk`) AS like_count 
                                    FROM `recipe` 
                                    JOIN `favourite` ON (recipe.`unique_id` = `favourite`.`recipe_unique_id_fk`) 
                                    JOIN `user` ON (recipe.`user_unique_id_fk` = user.`unique_id`) 
                                    WHERE favourite.`user_unique_id_fk` = ?
                                    ORDER BY recipe.`add_date` DESC
                                    LIMIT ?, 10");
    $converted_limit = intval($limit);                      

    $stmt->bind_param("si", $user_unique_id, $limit);   
    $result = $stmt->execute();

    if ($result) {
        $myArray = array();

        // Fetching Rows From Query
        while ($row = $result->get_result()->fetch()) {
            $myArray[] = $row;
        }
        $stmt->close();

        return $myArray;
    } else {
        return NULL;
    }
}
```

Here I try do encode it:

```
<?php
require_once 'include/DB_Functions.php';
$db = new DB_Functions();

// Receiving The Post Params
$user_unique_id = $_POST['user_unique_id_fk'];
$limit = $_POST['limit'];

// Getting Result Array
$resultArray = $db->getUserFavouriteRecipes($user_unique_id, $limit);
echo json_encode($resultArray);
?>
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: What do you mean "the code does not work properly"? Does it give you an error? Or what? Explain the issue.

Comment: It always returns `[]` as an aoutput which means the tabel is null inside.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to fetch results using prepared statements is:

```
...    
$stmt->execute();
$myArr = array();
$tmp = array();
$stmt->bind_result($tmp['unique_id'], $tmp['title'], ...); // all fields in select
$i = 0;
while($stmt->fetch()) {
    $myArr[$i] = $tmp;
    $i++;
}
if (count($myArr) > 0) {
    return $myArr;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Now it should work. I accidentally returned true instead of the array.

Comment: I have tried your way but it always returns me null instead of an array. Here is the code: https://ideone.com/qwxNVm

Comment: I think I see my error, try now. However, I think that the other answer is better.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `PDOStatement::fetchAll()` to return an array containing all of the result set rows, like this:

```
public function getUserFavouriteRecipes($user_unique_id, $limit) {

    // your code

    $stmt->execute();
    return $stmt->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}

$resultArray = $db->getUserFavouriteRecipes($user_unique_id, $limit);
```

To encode the results you can do:

```
$json=json_encode($resultArray);
```

And if you want to display the results, you can do something like this:

```
//loop over the $resultArray, setting $result to an array representing each row
foreach($resultArray as $result){
    //loop over each $result (row), setting $key to the column name and $value to the value in the column.
    foreach($result as $key=>$value){
        //echo the key and value.
        echo "{$key} = {$value}<br>";
    }
}
```

**Edited:**

```
public function getUserFavouriteRecipes($user_unique_id, $limit) {

    // your code

    $status = $stmt->execute();

    $myArray = array();
    if($status){
        // Extract result set and loop rows
        $result_set = $stmt->get_result();

        while($result = $result_set->fetch_assoc()){
            $myArray[] = $result;
        }
        return $myArray;
    }else{
        return NULL;
    }

}

$resultArray = $db->getUserFavouriteRecipes($user_unique_id, $limit);
$json = json_encode($resultArray);
```

**Your issue lies here:**

The following illustrates the `LIMIT` clause syntax with two arguments:

```
SELECT 
    column1,column2,...
FROM
    table
LIMIT offset , count;
```

Let’s examine the `LIMIT` clause parameters:

- The `offset` specifies the offset of the first row to return. The `offset` of the first row is 0, not 1.
- The `count` specifies maximum number of rows to return.

[image]

**So the reason you're getting this `string '[]' (length=2)` result is because of the fact that it's not able to fetch any record based on your `offset` and `count`.**

Try this:

```
public function getUserFavouriteRecipes($user_unique_id, $limit) {
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT recipe.`unique_id`, recipe.`title`, recipe.`img_tumbnail_link`, recipe.`add_date`, recipe.`kitchen_type`, recipe.`meal_type`, user.`name`, user.`surname`, 
                                    (SELECT count(*) from `like` WHERE recipe.`unique_id` = `like`.`recipe_unique_id_fk`) AS like_count 
                                    FROM `recipe` 
                                    JOIN `favourite` ON (recipe.`unique_id` = `favourite`.`recipe_unique_id_fk`) 
                                    JOIN `user` ON (recipe.`user_unique_id_fk` = user.`unique_id`) 
                                    WHERE favourite.`user_unique_id_fk` = ?
                                    ORDER BY recipe.`add_date` DESC
                                    LIMIT ?");
    $converted_limit = intval($limit);                      

    $stmt->bind_param("si", $user_unique_id, $converted_limit);   

    $status = $stmt->execute();

    $myArray = array();
    if($status){
        // Extract result set and loop rows
        $result_set = $stmt->get_result();

        while($result = $result_set->fetch_assoc()){
            $myArray[] = $result;
        }
        return $myArray;
    }else{
        return NULL;
    }
}

$resultArray = $db->getUserFavouriteRecipes($user_unique_id, $limit);
$json = json_encode($resultArray);
//var_dump($json);
```

Comment: I have tried like you told me but i get an error: `Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::fetchAll()`. Hehe is corrected code: https://ideone.com/81lwLx

Comment: @anton86993 That's because you can't execute `fetchAll()` on a `mysqli_stmt` object. PDO is not the same thing as mysqli. I've updated my answer. Please see the **edited** section of my answer.

Comment: @anton86993 You can see the encoded json object using `var_dump($json);`. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Here u can see the result: http://anton869.linuxpl.eu/android_login_api/loadfavouriterecipes.php It still returns null :(( This is corrected function: https://ideone.com/Hh4krr

Comment: @anton86993 Is it the output you're getting after incorporating my edited answer?

Comment: Yes, I used even var_dump and get sth like this: `string(2) "[]"`.

Comment: @anton86993 I think I figured out your issue. Are you trying to impose any `offset` in your LIMIT clause?

Comment: I am posting 2 params: `userId` and `?, 10` where ? is limit parameter

Comment: @anton86993 I've updated my answer. Please see the **Your issue lies here** section.

Comment: I am giving in my code 2 POST params:  `params.put("user_unique_id_fk", userUniqueId)` and `params.put("limit", Integer.toString(offset))` and this offset is 0 with 1st request. However I am still getting [] as a response. Why? In phpMyAdmin it works fine with 0,10...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96442/discussion-between-rajdeep-paul-and-anton86993).